# where does exactly getFilesDir() method address?

Tags: java, android

I have some files you can say a trained model that I need to get their path in my activity class.
I want to use `getFilesDir()`but it return "`data/user/0/com.example.abc/files/`".

I just don't know which folder or directory I have to paste my files exactly in order to be in this path so that these file can be get through `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: different devices running different android versions will return a different absolute path. If you just want to debug and test you can find it in your device file explorer in Android studio. Otherwise you should refrain from hardcoding your paths.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want use Asset. before run application, I have to paste this folder in some folder in projects, right? Where I have to paste them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the folder on your device

You can find it by opening "Device File Explorer" (this is a collapsed tab in the bottom right of your Android Studio - written vertically on the right edge, bottom)

There you open the folders `data/data/com.yourpackage.name/files`

Upload your files to this folder and your app can pick them up.

Hope this helps.

Use this way only to test things. For a production scenario you need to package your files in the project, like in the `raw` or `assets` folders of your app's resources, so they are contained in the .apk or .aab app bundle.

You can not access this folder via Windows Explorer. The Device must be in developer mode and adb must be running, so you can only access it through android studio or adb command shell. Keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks. getFilesDir() return "data/user/0/com.example.xxx/files/" path. in "Device File Explorer" there is  "data/data/com.example.xxx/files/"  and I can not create user folder inside data, error says this folder exist but it isn't.

Comment: You can create folders in `files` or in `com.example.xxx`. Not in the `/data`. And you did not tell how you tried to create a folder.

Comment: `getFilesDir() return "data/user/0/com.example.xxx/files/"` No. It returns `/data/user/0/com.example.xxx/files/`.

Comment: I did right click on data folder in "Device File Explorer" and click on " New" then "Directory". I insert user as a name of new folder and then click OK.
Yes you are right. getFilesDir() return /data/user/0/com.example.xxx/files/ but my point is on  "Device File Explorer", I have "data/data/com.example.xxx/files/" and these two directory are totaly diferent.

Comment: I still have problem to address my files. 
getFilesDir() return "/data/user/0/com.example.xxx/files/" but my data is in /data/data/com.example.xxx/files/ and I can not create the directory  "/data/user/0/com.example.xxx/files/".
Is there any solution???